# Angular: can I enforce at compile time that an input binding must be set?

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "test-component",
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html"
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() option: "A" | "B";

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.option) {
      throw new Error("option input must be set");
    }

    doSomethingWithOption(this.option);
  }
}
```

It must be used like this:

```
<test-component [whichYears]="'A'"></test-component>
```

I want to enforce that the component **must** be passed the `option` attribute and it must be one of `A` or `B`.

The above component definition does enforce this requirement, but it does it at run-time.

If I write code like below, it will fail only when I navigate my app to the page that uses the component:

```
<test-component></test-component>
```

Is there a way I can have my build pipeline tell me I'm not using the component properly?  Ideally, I'd like a typescript compile error, but is there maybe an Angular tool or an eslint configuration that would help me?

Working around this by having a "default" value for `option` isn't really the point of this question. I want to know if I can write Angular components with specific API requirements like this and then have that usage be enforced at build-time.

The project is Angular 7.  For additional context, I am new to Angular and am coming from a React/Typescript background where a situation like this would be enforced during compile-time by default - maybe I'm just not doing this the "angular way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding the required parameter in the `selector` of your custom component.

```js
@Component({
  selector: "test-component[option]", // where option here is the required @Input parameter
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html"
})
```

Now if you try to use the component without passing `option`, you will get a compile-time error.

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to give a compile-time error?
When I do it, IDEA shows me a warning "Component or directive matching test-component element is out of the current Angular module's scope".  But it still compiles (now gives a runtime error of "Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'app-subject-offering-completion-year'.")

Comment: If you mean when you start the application using `ng serve`, no it doesn't show an error. The `@angular/compiler` gives you an error if you try to open the application. You are basically declaring a component with a required parameter so if you don't have another component that has the same selector without the required parameter, the error just tells you that there is no such component exists because it can't find a component that does not have that parameter as required.

Comment: You can easily test this using a basic StackBlitz example. Just add `[name]` to the selector in `hello.component.ts` and using `hello` in `app.component.ts` with and without `name`

Comment: Also, the template parse errors you talked about are not run-time errors, though they are being shown only when your application is opened on a browser, you can see that it is the compiler that throws the error